# SDL 2.0 OpenGL not drawing anything except background

Tags: opengl, c++, sdl, c, sdl2

My 'hello triangle' compiles well, no errors, but doesn't drawing anything. Here's my code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include "src/App.h"

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    App app(600, 400, false);
    app.Run();
    return 0;
}
```

**App.h**

```
#ifndef APP_H
#define APP_H

#include <SDL.h>

class App
{
public:
    explicit App(size_t win_width, size_t win_height, bool fullscreen_mode)
            : m_window_width(win_width), m_window_height(win_height),
            m_fullscreen(fullscreen_mode) {
        };

     void Run();

private:
    void Draw();                        
    void Update(double dt);            
    void Resize(size_t width, size_t height);  
    void ProcessEvents();         

private:
    size_t m_window_width;
    size_t m_window_height;
    bool m_fullscreen;
    bool is_done;
    SDL_Window* m_window;
    SDL_GLContext m_glcontext;
};

#endif // APP_H
```

**App.cpp**

```
#include "../App.h"
#include <SDL_opengl.h>
#include <cassert>

void App::Run()
{
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    m_window = SDL_CreateWindow("Okno gry",
                                SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                                m_window_width, m_window_height,
                                SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | (m_fullscreen?SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN:SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE));

    m_glcontext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(m_window);
    Resize(m_window_width, m_window_height);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_COMPATIBILITY);

    glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 0);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_EQUAL);

    is_done = false;
    size_t last_ticks = SDL_GetTicks();
    while(!is_done)
    {
        ProcessEvents();

        size_t ticks = SDL_GetTicks();
        double delta_time = (ticks - last_ticks) / 1000;
        last_ticks = ticks;

        if (delta_time > 0 )
        {
            Update(delta_time);
        }

        Draw();
    }
    SDL_Quit();
}

void App::Draw()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    {
        glColor3f(1, 1, 0);
        glVertex2f(1, 1);
        glVertex2f(0, 1);
        glVertex2f(0, 0);
    }
    glEnd();
    SDL_GL_SwapWindow(m_window);
}

void App::ProcessEvents()
{
    if (is_done) return;

    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        if (event.type == SDL_WINDOWEVENT && event.window.event == SDL_WINDOWEVENT_SIZE_CHANGED)     
        {
            Resize(event.window.data1, event.window.data2);
        }
        else if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)      
        {
            is_done = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void App::Resize(size_t width, size_t height)
{
    m_window_width = width;
    m_window_height = height;

    glViewport(0, 0, static_cast<int>(width), static_cast<int>(height));
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glOrtho(0, 1, 0, 1, -1, 10);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void App::Update(double dt)
{
    //printf("%d", dt);
}
```

Can anyone help? I don't know why it's not running.

Comment: Try defining the color for each vertex. If it still doesn't work, then your driver probably removed compatibility with the fixed function pipeline

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_SetAttribute?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryAPI%5Cb%29%7C%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29) page, I would say that you need to set your attributes *before* you create your context. From what I can see in your code, the attribute setting lines are doing nothing, and so the deprecated code is disabled. This would prevent your triangle from being displayed.